# Filter users by type Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, fetchxml

I am trying to exclude App Users from a view in Dynamics 365 CRM. The fetch xml is very simple:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="systemuser">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="businessunitid" />
    <attribute name="title" />
    <attribute name="address1_telephone1" />
    <attribute name="positionid" />
    <attribute name="systemuserid" />
    <order attribute="fullname" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="type" operator="ne" value="App User" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

I need to place a filter in my query like this seudo code: `<condition attribute="type" operator="ne" value="App User" />`, sort of a field that allows me to filter by user type. Is there any field that could deterministically say that a user is an app user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, *Non-interactive App user* will be created with the attribute **Access mode = 4** in system user entity. So this should work.

```
<condition attribute="accessmode" operator="ne" value="4" />
```